# How to Add List Item in SharePoint Using REST API in Android

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, rest, android

I'm working on **Android app**. I want To add List items in Particular SharePoint list using Rest API.

I can get list items from SharePoint using **REST API**. I don't know how to add list item in SharePoint list.

Any Help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Are you looking for code or API reference?

Comment: @RohitWaghela I want to Add SharePoint List Items

Comment: Please refer this link, may be this could help you out - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API

Comment: @VishalHalani If you will go through above link, you will find all the CRUD operations there. There is also one example they have given for Adding New Item in SharePoint list.

Comment: @RohitWaghela it was in JavaScript dear I want to do in Java.So how can I implement It?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was Solved My problem.you have to follow this steps**

1. first you have to make  HTTP request to get **FormDigestValue** using POST Method because its will not support GET Method.
   You can get this using below REST URL

   "https://YourSite.sharepoint.com/_api/contextinfo"
2. Then you can make HTTP POST request for Add Data In SharePoint Particular List with below REST URL

   "https://YourSite.sharepoint.com/_api/lists/getbytitle('Your_List_Name')/items"

Main things is that you have to Pass FormDigestValue in this request as well your Value which you want to  add in list in json format like below

```
{'__metadata':{'type':'SP.Data.Android_x005f_TasksListItem'},'Title':'" + titleValue + "','Age':'" + ageValue + "'}
```

**In this json You have to replace type of List which i have written like this 'SP.Data.Android_x005f_TasksListItem'**

you can get this list type with below REST URL just paste in browser or make web call.

```
your_sharepointsite/_api/lists/getbytitle('Your_List_Name')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName
```