# how to update the share point list using android?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, sharepont, android

I want to add item in sharepoint list using android but i  could not found any sutaible example or solution, any one has ans for that? i  tried this [solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171483/how-to-add-list-item-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api-in-android?rq=1)
 but its seem its does not work for me please give me some guidance.

```
__metadata:'type': 'SP.Data.SomeListItem'
 subject:'AnyThing'
 CommentDocumentName:'Data'
 comment:'add Docs'
 role:'Customer'
 AppID:'1234'
```

Comment: The REST API is the way to do this. The solution you cited is fine. What is your problem with that?

Comment: @Nils my issue it that when i sending all parameter using post i'm getting "The HTTP header Content-Type is missing or its value is invalid." do i need any other parameter to send?

Comment: my header is cookie:some value
Accept:application/json;odata=verbose
X-RequestDigest: some value
Content-Type:application/json;odata=verbose

Comment: So the question is not *"How do I use the SharePoint API"*, but rather *"How do I send a valid content-type http-header in an android app"*?

Comment: No question is valid i want to send the parameter from  android if you have any or example how to update the share point list i tried in both way but first i just want to test in postman but its does not work its seems.

Comment: i did not found any sniped in android to send the parameter to share point list using rest API except that getting the data from list.

Comment: yes according to docs they send header using ajax call so i just send it as per documentation.

Comment: @Nils any suggestion for this?

Comment: I added an answer. no "android", though. but it works using postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak "android", but using postman the following flow works for me:

Request "ContextInfo"

```
POST /_api/contextinfo HTTP/1.1
Host: my.sharepoint.local
Accept: application/json; odata=verbose
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: dac3ee21-85b6-4c86-8015-3bb9646e25a9,523b0e7b-7d02-4aee-b078-83af480696a1
Host: my.sharepoint.local
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache
```

which returns data.. i.e.:

```
{
    "d": {
        "GetContextWebInformation": {
            "__metadata": {
                "type": "SP.ContextWebInformation"
            },
            "FormDigestTimeoutSeconds": 1800,
            "FormDigestValue": "0x01524F8681FE5C746F329FA4CC040A709D0BCAFA2B6BA590397F40559C1787F314201BA81B0046F37CCF9C68282655AD042FC37B1A872670759B41FC9285FF3D,02 Jul 2019 13:03:18 -0000",
            "LibraryVersion": "16.0.4744.1000",
            "SiteFullUrl": "https://my.sharepoint.local",
            "SupportedSchemaVersions": {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type": "Collection(Edm.String)"
                },
                "results": [
                    "14.0.0.0",
                    "15.0.0.0"
                ]
            },
            "WebFullUrl": "https://my.sharepoint.local"
        }
    }
}
```

using that `FormDigestValue` as the `X-RequestDigest` in the next request:

```
POST /_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items? HTTP/1.1
Host: my.sharepoint.local
Accept: application/json; odata=verbose
Content-Type: application/json
X-RequestDigest: 0x01524F8681FE5C746F329FA4CC040A709D0BCAFA2B6BA590397F40559C1787F314201BA81B0046F37CCF9C68282655AD042FC37B1A872670759B41FC9285FF3D,02 Jul 2019 13:03:18 -0000
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 87735fcd-5f15-4f31-9b7e-62f5a3050b72,a798e358-5d14-4f26-9bfd-c50989850153
Host: my.sharepoint.local
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 29
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

 {
    'Title': 'New title' 
 }
```

Creates a new item in the list named `Test`.

Comment: for form digest value its worked its not worked for to add some content into target list for example if i need to add comment then i need to send parameter like comment as string type id as int of some other data this is not working.

Comment: Please post the list-json (i.e. the result of `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('YourName')`) and the post-data you are trying to send. I do not quite get what the problem seems to be.

Comment: ok i will try and let you know.

Comment: i just update the my queston with body value. please see that.

Comment: i have one dought using for digest these all value i need to send as header??

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand that question. But reading your example: Try *not* to send the `_metadata` information

Comment: My question is very simple i need to add some data into share point list through the rest API from android. that's it.

Comment: its working with raw data thanks